# New Computer Modern fonts: problem with accented bold sans serif letters

Tags: fonts

I am currently testing the New Computer Modern fonts for my own usage of LuaLaTeX with the MacTeX 2022 distribution, that is to say TeX Live 2022, to produce documents in French, my native language, which uses a lot of diacritics. I quickly noticed something weird: when using the bold sans serif font, the accented letters are noticeably bigger than the others.

For exemple, the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}% also loads fontspec (and unicode-math)
\begin{document}
\sffamily\bfseries dérivées
\end{document}
```

results in this:

[image]

As you can see, the accented "e" letters are much bigger than the not-accented letters, most notably the other "e". It doesn't happen if I use the usual Latin Modern fonts, which result in this:

[image]

Before filling a bug report, I would like to know if this behaviour is the same in other distributions (or other versions of these fonts, this one being 4.1), or if it's specific to the one I use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see it with vanilla Tex Live 2022 on Debian GNU/Linux.

Comment: I get the same in context and luametatex. Note also that the font looks completely different (the lm one is more rounded). I don't know if that is by design or not, though.

Comment: The difference is obvious even without compiling an example: just look at the outline window and the metrics window for the two glyphs in FontForge.

Comment: This is bug in the font. FontForge shows it. I have got the same bad result as shown here by OpTeX in TeXlive 2022.

Comment: OK, it seems not clear it is inherent to the font. I'll make a bug report to the author. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug report

Comment: `CTAN` released the new version yesterday, please check with that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that was a bug. The recently released version 4.7 fixes that.
[image]